# Sudo user without the permission to edit sudoers

Tags: sudo

How can I add an user to sudoers list with all privileges, but that user **should not be able to edit the sudoers file** ?

Comment: all previlege u say, and then talk of restricting?? hmm... `/me scratches head`

Comment: I want to block him to edit sudoers.

Comment: If you wish to give root access, nothing can stop him/her from messing up with your system. All privileges *means* No restrictions. Give only the permissions he needs. What exactly is your situation? If you edit the question to add this information, we may be able to help better.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the sudoers with the visudo command

```
sudo visudo
```

Add the user like this

```
theusername ALL=ALL, !/usr/sbin/visudo
```

Which will explicit disallow the user from running the visudo command with sudo.

However, this does not prevent them from running

```
sudo -s
```

to drop to a root shell, from which they can run the visudo command.

Comment: yes that is my problem. I want to block him to edit sudoers.

Comment: Or prevent him from editing `/ect/sudoers` with regular vim (or any other texteditor). I don't think there's any solution you would be happy with, because you're asking for contraditory things.